# Bootstrap 3 : How to fit responsive table in the container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to manage my tables on responsive view to fit in the container div. I wish that the elements are superimposed instead of overflowing after the container.

I tried this code but it doesn't work :

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
```

[My Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ecwvupkc/)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using bootstrap3, you have used the **`table-responsive`** class at wrong place. Just wrap your **`.table`** into div with class **`table-responsive`** and apply some **`min-width`** to your select elements for responsive purpose.

***[Reference Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive)***

```css
body {
  background: #D3D3D3;
  margin: 20px;
}

.container {
  background: white;
}

select {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" role="main">
      <h2>Test Table</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-curved">
          <tbody class="text-nowrap">
            <tr>
              <th class="info bold-italic col-md-3" scope="row">This is long title from my table 1</th>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control selectwidthauto input-sm text-center">
                  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choisissez une option</option>
                  <option value="oui">Oui</option>
                  <option value="non">Non</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <th class="info bold-italic col-md-3" scope="row">This is long title from my table 2</th>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control selectwidthauto input-sm text-center">
                  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choisissez une option</option>
                  <option value="oui">Oui</option>
                  <option value="non">Non</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="info bold-italic col-md-3" scope="row">This is long title from my table 3</th>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control selectwidthauto input-sm text-center">
                   <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choisissez une option</option>
                   <option value="oui">Oui</option>
                   <option value="non">Non</option>
                 </select>
              </td>
              <th class="info bold-italic col-md-3" scope="row">This is long title from my table 4</th>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control selectwidthauto input-sm text-center">
                  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choisissez une option</option>
                  <option value="oui">Oui</option>
                  <option value="non">Non</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="info bold-italic col-md-3" scope="row">This is long title from my table 5</th>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control selectwidthauto input-sm text-center">
                  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choisissez une option</option>
                  <option value="oui">Oui</option>
                  <option value="non">Non</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <th class="info bold-italic col-md-3" scope="row">This is long title from my table 6</th>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control selectwidthauto input-sm text-center">
                  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choisissez une option</option>
                  <option value="oui">Oui</option>
                  <option value="non">Non</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, my mistake was to forgot one div where i put the responsive class. Great thank you very muck for this quick fix :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using `text-nowrap` on the `tbody` element. This adds this CSS:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

which means the contents of the cells don't wrap, which in turn fixes the minimum width. This means they cannot be responsive. Remove that and your table will fit.